# How to get specific node as object by its ID in Drupal-specific Twig?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

The only way I found yet is

```
{{ drupal_entity('node', '123', 'body') }}
```

Here *123* is ID/NID of a node

That always gives me node body and title (even if I specify 'title' instead of 'body')

Is there a way to get specific node as object in Drupal Twig to be able then to access available properties of the object?

Drupal 8.9.16

*Please do not remove the word **"Twig"** in the title as we can get data both in PHP and Twig template and I need in Drupal-specific Twig only*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. We can get the object of specific node by its ID in Twig the way like

```
{% set nodeTeaser = drupal_entity('node', 123, 'teaser') %}
{% set nodeObj = nodeTeaser['#node'] %}
```

Then we can get any of available properties like

```
{% set nodeType = nodeObj.type %}
```

or

```
{% set nodeBody = nodeObj.body.0.value %}
```